# Not able to avoid max-height for scrollable content div

Tags: html, css

In the **grid-area main**, I have a scrollable div that needs to occupy all the available space, all together filling up to the device heigh. Now, with max-height it is not able to occupy up to the available space.

```html
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
      grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr auto;
      grid-template-columns: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      margin: -18px -24px 0px -24px; border: 0px; padding:0px ">

  <div style="grid-area: header; background-color: green; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px">
    <br />

  </div>

  <div style="grid-area: main; background-color: blue;  ">
    <!-- This needs to occupy the rest of the space, now limited by max-height -->
    <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; padding: 20px; min-height:15px; max-height:265px">
      Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space
Scrollable Content that needs to be occupying the available space

    </div>

  </div>

  <div style="color: black; background-color: black; grid-area: footer; padding: 10px; text-align: center">
    some footer content

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you investigated flex?

Comment: You need to understand `height: 100%` probably doesn't do what you want. Its behavior depends on its immediate parent container.

Comment: min-height:0 to grid-area:main